# What is the correct way to create webservice interface for inserting records using Swagger/Swashbuckle?

Tags: .net, web-services, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm building an .Net based web service (using Swagger and Swashbuckle).
I'm new to the tools and having some issues with exposing a call to insert data.

**This is what my datamodel class looks like on the server:**

```
public class User 
{
  public long? UserCode { get; set; }
  public string UserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  public string EmailAddress { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  public string SomeOtherField1 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  public string SomeOtherField2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

**This is what my service definition (controller) looks like:**

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AuditSettingUserController : Controller
{
  private AppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

  public AuditSettingUserController(IOptions<AppSettings> settings)
  {
    AppSettings = settings.Value;
  }

  [HttpPut()]
  [Route("api/DashboardSettings/CreateUser/{userrecord}")]
  public void CreateUser(User userrecord)
  {
  } 
}
```

This is what the call looks like from the client side:

```
IO.Swagger.Api.SettingUserApi dsApi = new IO.Swagger.Api.SettingUserApi("http://localhost:56995");
IO.Swagger.Model.User record = new IO.Swagger.Model.User()
{
   UserCode = 100,
   UserName = "Foo",
   EmailAddress = "Foo2"
};
string sSerializedRecord = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(record);
dsApi.ApiSettingUserApiSettingsCreateUserByUserrecordPut(sSerializedRecord);
```

Everything build successfully and runs with out errors.

However there are two issues.
First, when I look at the service call method definition in the generated code on the client side, I'm a little confused. I don't understand the prototype that was generated.

**The definition looks like this:**

```
public void ApiSettingUserApiSettingsCreateUserByUserrecordPut (string userrecord, long? userCode = null, string userName = null, string emailAddress = null, string SomeOtherField1 = null, string SomeOtherField2 = null)
```

Secondly, on the server side, the record passed in is empty. (The record is not null, but the values inside are null/empty).

What am I doing wrong here? Do I not have my service call, its parameters defined correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the service method definition and it's decorations.

```
[HttpPut()]
[Route("api/DashboardSettings/CreateUser/{userrecord}")]
public void CreateUser(User userrecord)
{
}
```

**Should be:**

```
[HttpPut()]
[Route("api/DashboardSettings/CreateUser")]
public void CreateUser(User userrecord)
{
}
```

By having the method parameter included in the [Route] definition, the method was expecting the parameter to be part of the command line. 
I removed the parameter from the [Route] and all works as expected.